# Next.js - API call from different page is not loading the data

Tags: javascript, next.js

Hello everyone I am extremely new at the Next.js world.

I am using the getStaticProps() to make an API call and in order to make it little organized, i have created a separate page "git" under "pages" folder and here is my code:

```
function Git({ stars }) {
    return <div>Next stars: {stars}</div>
  }

export async function getStaticProps() {
    const res = await fetch('https://api.github.com/repos/vercel/next.js')
    const json = await res.json()
    return { stars: json.stargazers_count }
}

export default Git
```

And i am trying to load the API data to the index.js file under the "pages" folder.

Inside the index.js file, i am using below to load the API data from the "Git" page

```
import fetch from "isomorphic-unfetch"
import Git from './Git'
```

And under the following

```
render () {
    return (
    <Git />
```

On the browser, i am not seeing the API data but i am seeing the HTML from the "Git" page

```
<div>Next stars: </div>
```

Is there any way if i can load the API data from different page to the index.js page?

However, if i directly access the page for example: http://0.0.0.0:3000/Git then i get the proper API data.

**Issue**
The issue is about the API data in the page "Git" is not getting passed to the main page "index.js" is there any way if i can pass the data from the "Git" to the "index.js"

Comment: Try `return { props: { stars: json.stargazers_count }}` instead (also note that the fetch() in getStaticProps runs at build time, so once the app is published, the value will never update)

Comment: In addition to the above, `getStaticProps` only works on page components, it won't work if it's inside a component that you use in a page. It doesn't matter if the component is under the `pages` folder, `getStaticProps` needs to be exported from the page you're accessing.

Comment: I tried this return { props: { stars: json.stargazers_count }} but i am still not seeing the data

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by putting the following code in the index.js file

```
const gitData = await Git.getInitialProps();
```

And that's where I want to print it out

```
 <Git {...this.props.gitData}/>
```